# How can reduce the time of query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table called ResultValues where I have 6 columns, 4 are integers, 1 is datatime and 1 is varbinary (1640).

Total number of records are '27,389,918' so this table is very huge. now when i run this query

```
select LineNo ,TraceNo, DateTime ,Bin from ResultValues
where ID = 8115
Order by DateTime ASC
```

I created NON Clustered Index on UniqueID, ID, LineNo, TraceNo and it gives me 987014.

Question: It's still taking same time what I was taking before Non Clustered Index. can someone tell me how can i reduce the number of time using this query. Please suggest.

Comment: Is ID is a unique value?

Comment: What does the query plan say? In all likelyhood it's not using the index. Try creating an index with ID first.

Comment: NO, its not. Non of them are unique. Unique ID is not unique id either.

Comment: What is 987014? Number of rows or query duration? If number of rows, then it should take a while to transfer data from server to application

Comment: Do ypu really want result to be sorted by DateTime. The result requires 987014 items to be sorted. You can somehow filter the data more fastly by creating the clustered index over ID. But stil sortig will take time.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an index on `id, other columns` is not a good idea.

Create an index *just* on `id`. You should find your query times to be a lot better.

The reason is two-fold:

- id is unique, so adding more columns to the index won't create any more index entries, so no performance or efficiency is being created
- the index entries will be a lot smaller, so the index can be scanned more quickly, leading to faster query times

The only time when such an index is "useful" is for an index-only query, where all data may be retrieved from the index, without going to the table. However, this is a very specific/niche performance technique that IMHO has little value. I have worked with many production systems, including very large web-based companies, and have never seen such indexes defined. They are very expensive for the database to maintain, and usually cause much more harm than good, and the good is minimal.

Comment: Having an index on single column is (almost) never a good idea!

Comment: Assuming that 987,014 is number of rows that would mean 987,014 lookups to retrieve the missing columns. Quite possibly the index would not be used and even if it was this would still be expensive. (I know `ID` sounds like it should be unique but they also mention a column called `UniqueID`)

Comment: @nenad on the contrary. Creating indexes on one column is the norm. Many databases do it implicitly when foreign keys are defined.

Comment: I don't know about 'many databases' but I can assure you SQL Server will, way more often then not - IGNORE such an indexes as it's more expensive to use them then just to do scan. I've wrote something about it awhile ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697992/what-does-a-sql-select-statement-actually-do-during-execution/15700906#15700906 (This is somewhat simplified though, but if needed it can be explained in more details)

Comment: ps: You are assuming ID is unique - in which case, yes it could be usable to have index on it, however OP have stated that it's not unique.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic you are gravely mistaken. Single-column indexes are the cornerstone of databases. The only time they would not be used is when there are so few rows in the table (or there are so few distinct values in the index) that it's cheaper to scan the whole table than read the index pages then read the necessary table pages, which frankly is an edge-case barely worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_id_DateTime__LineNo_TraceNo_Bin 
ON (ID, DateTime)  INCLUDE (LineNo ,TraceNo, Bin)
```

This should be your covering index for particular query - it should give you best results.